# Dois menus verticais em ambas as laterais do navegador

Tags: html, css

Veja a imagem:

[image: Tela]

O conteúdo (um script three.js) ocuparia 100% do viewport(padding:0;border:0;margin:0), já os menus ocupariam 10% de largura por 100% de altura.No caso do menu 1, consigo usando position:fixed, no entanto o menu 2 não dá certo, nem com position:fixed nem com float:right.
Seria algo como isso:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Game
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="three.min.js"></script>
        <div id="left">
            <a href="#" class="active">Menu 1</a>
            <a href="#">link 1.1</a>
            <a href="#">link 1.2</a>
            <a href="#">link 1.3</a>
            <a href="#">link 1.4</a>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <a href="#" class="active">Menu 2</a>
            <a href="#">link 2.1</a>
            <a href="#">link 2.2</a>
            <a href="#">link 2.3</a>
            <a href="#">link 2.4</a>
        </div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Comment: Não funciona se fizer um margin: 0 0 0 80%;(ou 90% se o parâmetro for a outra borda) ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o que faltou para você foi apenas colocar `right: 0` no seu `#right`, indicando que ele está fixo à direita. Segue um exemplo que eu criei:

```css
#left {
  /* Fixo à esquerda e topo, ocupando toda altura */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* Para ficar atrás do texto */ 
  z-index: -1;

  /* Para os links ficarem em linhas diferentes */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  
  /* Para visualizar melhor */
  background-color: red;
}

#right {
  /* Fixo à direita e topo, ocupando toda altura */
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  
  /* Para ficar atrás do texto */ 
  z-index: -1;
  
  /* Para os links ficarem em linhas diferentes */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  
  /* Para visualizar melhor */
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla id elementum augue. Pellentesque ac purus accumsan urna egestas vestibulum. Phasellus non dui aliquam, euismod augue hendrerit, porta mauris. Duis dignissim arcu in luctus consectetur. Nulla iaculis neque in suscipit faucibus. Nulla pulvinar mauris tellus. Aenean ligula augue, viverra at viverra ut, vestibulum in eros. Proin posuere ex sed arcu faucibus, semper consectetur leo faucibus. Etiam consequat cursus velit, sed hendrerit justo sollicitudin vitae.</p>
<div id="left">
  <a href="#" class="active">Menu 1</a>
  <a href="#">link 1.1</a>
  <a href="#">link 1.2</a>
  <a href="#">link 1.3</a>
  <a href="#">link 1.4</a>
</div>
<div id="right">
  <a href="#" class="active">Menu 2</a>
  <a href="#">link 2.1</a>
  <a href="#">link 2.2</a>
  <a href="#">link 2.3</a>
  <a href="#">link 2.4</a>
</div>
```

Caso você não precise que o menu fique atrás do texto, ou não quer usar `display: flex`, é só ler o comentário que eu coloquei em cada estilo CSS e remover :)

PS: Não quis modificar o seu HTML para não dificultar o entendimento, mas pegue os atributos em comuns de ambos os menus e coloque em uma classe, não duplique código.